# Tuning Swagger-UI for REST API

Tags: jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to tune Swagger-UI for Java REST API.
Requirements:

1. Add description of REST path
2. Add dropdown for multi produces (I was able to do so, but cannot replicate again)
3. Add example(s) to be selected like in "Model schema"

Thanks in advance.

```
@Component
@Path("/test")
@Api(value = "/test",
    description = "Demo of how to pass JSON/XML document to the REST services", 
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "," + MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "," + MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public class TerminologyRest2 {

    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @ApiOperation(value = "Creates a product", 
                  notes = "Creates a product and puts it in the catalog.", 
                  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "," + MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, 
                  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "," + MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, 
                  protocols = "POST", 
                  response = Product.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Malformed definition of new product", response = StatusInfo.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error", response = StatusInfo.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful catalogization of new product", response = Product.class)
            })
    public Response createProduct(@ApiParam(name = "product", required = true, value = "Define product content") Product product) {
        try {

            return Response.status(200).entity(product).build();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
        }
    }
}
```

Currently:

[image]

Wanted:

[image]

Comment: Which version of swagger-core do you use?

Comment: Hi. I only use: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
   <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.12</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I assume this is a new integration. As such, the first step would be the latest version and not the ones you use. Please follow the guides in the wiki based on the JAX-RS implementation you use - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup-1.5.X.